# Kotlin returns object with unassigned properties after assigning them in apply function

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, assign, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to do a quite simple task: assign properties to an object and return that same object after retrieving the infos with a REST call.

In my runBlocking block I use the apply function to change the properties of my object, but after trying different ways to assign them, instantiate the object itself, modifying constructing logic of the object, I still get an object with the default values.

Here's my Info object:

```
class DrivingLicenceInfo {
     var type : String = ""
     var nationality : String = ""
     var number : String = ""
     var releaseDate : String = ""
     var expiryDate : String = ""
}
```

Here's the method which gives me problems:

```
    private fun getDerivingLicenceInfoAndWaitForCompletion(): DrivingLicenceInfo {

        return runBlocking {
            val response = retrieveDrivingLicenceInfoAsync().await()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                var info = DrivingLicenceInfo()
                response.body()?.let {

                    info.apply {
                        it.data.let { data ->
                            val type = data.guy
                            val drivingLicenseNationality = data.drivingLicenseNationality
                            val drivingLicenseNumber = data.drivingLicenseNumber
                            val drivingReleaseDate = data.drivingReleaseDate
                            val drivingExpiryDate = data.drivingExpiryDate

                            this.type = type
                            this.nationality = drivingLicenseNationality
                            this.number = drivingLicenseNumber
                            this.releaseDate = drivingReleaseDate
                            this.expiryDate = drivingExpiryDate
                        }
                    }
                    info
                    Log.i("driving.info.call", info.type)
                }
            }
            DrivingLicenceInfo()
        }
    }
```

And here's where I use it, in my Main, and where I get an info object with empty strings as properties

```
    private void getDrivingLicenceData() {
        DrivingLicenceInfoService service = new DrivingLicenceInfoServiceImpl(context);
        DrivingLicenceInfo info = service.getDrivingLicenceInfo();
        Log.i("driving.info.main",info.getType());
        profileViewModel.licenceNumber.postValue(info.getNumber());
        profileViewModel.licenceExpiryDate.postValue(info.getExpiryDate());
    }
```

The log in the runBlocking correctly shows the property, the log in my Main doesn't even show up.
Using the debugger I am able to see that info has empty strings as value.

Could somebody help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You're returning `DrivingLicenceInfo()` at the end of your runBlocking call is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @JeelVankhede already told you the main reason of your problem and I also have some suggestions apart from the one given by @WarrenFaith.

If `DrivingLicenceInfo` is a model class you can declare it as `data class` like

```
data class DrivingLicenceInfo (
  val type : String = "",
  val nationality : String = "",
  val number : String = "",
  val releaseDate : String = "",
  val expiryDate : String = ""
)
```

you can read more about data class [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

And then you can write your function as

```
private fun getDerivingLicenceInfoAndWaitForCompletion(): DrivingLicenceInfo {
    val info = runBlocking {
      val response = retrieveDrivingLicenceInfoAsync().await()
      if (response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let {
          it.data.let { data ->
            DrivingLicenceInfo(
              type = data.guy,
              nationality = data.drivingLicenseNationality,
              number = data.drivingLicenseNumber,
              releaseDate = data.drivingReleaseDate,
              expiryDate = data.drivingExpiryDate
            )
          }
        } ?: DrivingLicenceInfo()
      } else {
        DrivingLicenceInfo()
      }
    }
    Log.i("driving.info.call", info.type)
    return info
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside @JeelVankhede giving you the main reason for your problem, I suggest some minor code improvements as well. I personally feel this is ways less verbose and better readable

```
private fun getDrivingLicenceInfoAndWaitForCompletion(): DrivingLicenceInfo {
    return runBlocking {
        val response = retrieveDrivingLicenceInfoAsync().await()
        var info = DrivingLicenceInfo()    
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let {
                info.apply {
                    type = it.data.guy
                    nationality = it.data.drivingLicenseNationality
                    number = it.data.drivingLicenseNumber
                    releaseDate = it.data.drivingReleaseDate
                    expiryDate = it.data.drivingExpiryDate
                }
                Log.i("driving.info.call", info.type)
                info
            } ?: info
        } else { info }
    }
}
```